# Braintree SDK payment issue - IOS + Php

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, payment-gateway, braintree

I am using BrainTree sandbox account. I am using marketplace and perform following sale method from api. I hold the transaction in escrow and try to release but i fail to do so. Anyone has experience in BrainTree Marketplace?

Following are the parameter i am passing:

```
Braintree_Transaction::sale(
                          [
                        'amount' => 10,
                        'merchantAccountId' => SubMerchantID,
                        'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient,
                        'options' => array(
                              'submitForSettlement' => true,
                              'holdInEscrow' => true
                            ),
                            'serviceFeeAmount' => 2
                          )
                      ];
```

I want to  hold transaction in Escrow. The above sale is successfully done but i can not release transaction from Escrow. (I need help in this)

I have used below code to release payment :-

```
Braintree_Transaction::releaseFromEscrow($userdata->transaction_id);
```

When i try to release transaction i got following error:
      "**Cannot release a transaction that is not escrowed.**"

I find transaction details by Braintree_Transaction find method and it shows all the details about transaction and **escrowStatus** is **hold_pending**.

I get to know from documentation that I need to change status to "Held". But I am not sure how ?

I am sure that escrowStatus is cause this problem.

Now what to do to release transaction from escrow?

Please let me know if i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Braintree are helpful and respond within ~12 hours normally, give them a shot:

support@braintreepayments.com

I've been dealing with them for the last few months. Send them a copy of your posts' text. I find you don't have to be very formal with them.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction’s escrow status will be hold pending while the transaction has a status of submitted for settlement and that escrow status will switch to held once the transaction has a status of settled. You can [click here](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/wells-flat/transactions/settlement-funding-timeline) to see the settlement timeline for Marketplace merchants. You can generally expect transactions that have a hold pending to switch to held on that schedule.

I hope this helps.